# How to correctly use an "external" JS module for PhpStorm completion?

Tags: docker, phpstorm, package.json

This question involves: Git submodules, Docker, JavaScript, Nuxt.

## The situation

There are 2 projects:

- `back`: contains docker containers with API and **compiled js files for gRPC**, this is a git submodule.
- `front`: consume those **js files**

The package manager used is `yarn`.

## Current setup

Folder Architecture is as follow

```
.
+-- back (git submodule)
    +-- js
        +-- file1
        +-- file1
+-- front
    +-- package.json
```

`front` has a declared volume that link to the js files:

```
front:
  volumes:
    - ../back/js:/usr/src/app/js_back:ro
```

Then I can refer to those files using:

```
import ... from '@/js_back/...'
```

The problem is that PhpStorm does not know that `@/js_back/...` is in reality `../back/js`

Also, as those files are often required, I would have love to be able to refer to those with `@back/...`.

## Alternatives

1. Declare a dependency in `package.json` that link to the files. => This does not seem to work
2. Publish the JS part under a custom package registry. => Those files are tightly coupled with the `back` so this would be harder to maintain.
3. Hint PhpStorm about the files location. => I saw "Mark Directory as Resource Root" on some other questions, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: where does `@` come from? Is it an alias defined somewhere in your build files (webpack, etc)? The you can use [webpack integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-webpack.html) to get these aliases resolved. or, just define your aliases in [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases) placed in the project root folder

Comment: The `@` are defined by default in Nuxt https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-alias.

Comment: Oh just noticed that the "Declare a dependency in package.json that link to the files." works after yarn install as it copy the directory under `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution. In my <kbd>package.json</kbd> I did declare

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@my/back": "file:./js_back"
  }
}
```

After a `yarn install` the content get copied under <kbd>node_modules</kbd> so PHPStorm can see it properly and provide completion accordingly.